# Debian: Startup in Console Mode?

Tags: debian

How can I not use the graphical desktop when starting up Debian on my server? I cannot use the graphical desktop because my VGA does not support the set resolution.

Comment: Press Ctrl-Alt-F1, and then you might find this helpful... http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-boot-debian-in-text-mode-instead-of-graphical-mode-gui.html

Answer (score 1):

The normal setup is that X login managers (like xdm, gdm, etc) only start in runlevel 3.

Therefore I think the most reasonable way to your goal is to edit /etc/inittab so that you boot to runlevel 2. Look for the line with "default" in it, and set default runlevel to two this way:

id:2:initdefault:

If you would like to boot to runlevel 2 and then start X at a later time, you could ensure the "xinit" package is installed, and run "startx" once you would like to start X. If you decide you're tired of booting to console, I suggest booting to runlevel 3 by editing /etc/inittab. On the fly, you could also run "telinit 3" to change to runlevel 3.

Note that runlevels can also be set via boot parameters. Although that's more sensible for  one-off rescue scenarios (e.g., boot to single-user mode to perform some recovery tasks).

Answer (score 0):

Append `single` to the kernel line in grub / lilo, it should drop you to shell then you can edit Xorg config.